# When is a form displayed?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am trying to figure out when exactly the `Form.Load` event occurs. In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) it sais:

> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

But when the form is displayed for the first time? My first instinct was immediately after `InitializeComponent()`, but when I tried the following code, the `MessageBox` showed `5` even though the value was set after `InitializeComponent()`, so it's not immediately after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int number;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        number = 5;
    }

    public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(number);
    }
}
```

So When does it occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OnLoad` is one of the methods being called when you call `Show` or `ShowDialog` on a `Form`.

The first time you call `Show` or `ShowDialog`, `OnLoad` is called and your `Load` event is fired. (Just like `OnHandleCreated`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx

This explains the order of startup and shutdown of forms.

In short, a number of events are triggered in order - eg create...load...activate..shown ..